# How to know UIWebView webViewDidFinishLoad occurs finally in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, toolbar

Twitter app shows webView without toolbar. And then when tap a link on web page, `webView` shows toolbar on bottom.

I coded as below, but I found `webViewDidFinishLoad()` occurs several times.

How to know `webViewDidFinishLoad()` occurs finally?

```
iNavigate = 0;


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{    

    iNavigate ++;


    NSLog(@"Navigate Count = %d", iNavigate);


    if (iNavigate >1)
    {
        CGRect rect = self.webView.frame;
        rect.size.height = rect.size.height - toolBarBrowser.frame.size.height;
        self.webView.frame = rect;
        self.toolBarBrowser.hidden = FALSE;
    }

    barButtonBack.enabled = (self.webView.canGoBack);
    barButtonForward.enabled = (self.webView.canGoForward);



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `(webview.isLoading)` to know UIWebView webViewDidFinishLoad occurs finally or not

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview  {
   if (webview.isLoading)
       return;
   else
   {
       CGRect rect = self.webView.frame;
       rect.size.height = rect.size.height - toolBarBrowser.frame.size.height;
       self.webView.frame = rect;
       self.toolBarBrowser.hidden = FALSE;

       barButtonBack.enabled = (self.webView.canGoBack);
       barButtonForward.enabled = (self.webView.canGoForward);
   }
 }
```